# Diagram to Represent Ruby on Rails Structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, structure, diagram

A class diagram is pretty good for capturing the structure of a Java desktop application.  But a Ruby on Rails project is organized differently than Java due to its MVC architecture.  What would be the best type of diagram for conveying the structure of a Ruby on Rails program? Since the word "best" is subjective....what diagram or diagrams would effectively convey the overall structure of a Rails project?

Comment: Swing is also MVC (and a pretty good one). It's not clear what you actually want to communicate, but [railroady](https://github.com/preston/railroady) has been useful to me in the past. To be honest, I find most diagrams like that too low-level to provide an "overall structure", really.

Comment: I found rubymine (editor) generates the model dependency diagram, which sorts of giving an overview how the data models are designed and associated.

Comment: @DaveNewton seems shared a great information. Thanks dave.

Comment: That's really interesting to know.  I've been using Swing without even knowing that it was MVC.  I did come across railroady when browsing this topic.  I'll have to look into it further.

Comment: @Daron http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html Just beware of overly-precise definitions of "MVC" because it can be implemented in a variety of ways.

Comment: I'd recommend you watch Uncle Bob on his "Architecture: The Lost Years [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WpkDN78P884]. It's enlightening on this subject =]

Comment: Yes, I'll definitely watch that.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out rails-erd gem: https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd

It automatically generates an ERD diagram based on your models and associations, pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your information.  In reality ALL responses have been helpful and appreciated.  But I am marking this as the answer since it is the only one presented as an answer rather than comment.